# Tensorflow: Invalid calculations

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new into tensorflow and try to understand how the computation graph works. I am working on the very basic linear regression example on the tensorflow website. I have the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def manual_loss(_w, _b, _x, _y):
    _loss = 0.0
    n = len(_x)
    for j in range(n):
       _loss += (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j]) ** 2
    return _loss


def manual_grads(_w, _b, _x, _y):
     n = len(_x)
     g_w = 0.0
     g_b = 0
     for j in range(n):
         g_w += 2.0 * (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j]) * _x[j]
         g_b += 2.0 * (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j])
     return g_w, g_b


# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([0.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-0.3], dtype=tf.float32)
_W = 0.3
_b = -0.3
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y))  # sum of the squares
grads = tf.gradients(loss, [W, b])
# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)  
lr = 0.001
for i in range(1000):
    results = sess.run([loss, W, b, grads], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    loss_value = results[0]
    W_value = results[1]
    b_value = results[2]
    grad_W = results[3][0]
    grad_b = results[3][1]
    manual_loss_value = manual_loss(_w=_W, _b=_b, _x=x_train, _y=y_train)
    manual_grad_W, manual_grad_b = manual_grads(_w=_W, _b=_b, _x=x_train, _y=y_train)
    new_W_value = W_value - lr * grad_W
    new_b_value = b_value - lr * grad_b
    W = tf.assign(W, value=new_W_value)
    b = tf.assign(b, value=new_b_value)
    print("***********************")
    print("loss={0}".format(loss_value))
    print("manual_loss_value={0}".format(manual_loss_value))
    print("W={0}".format(W_value))
    print("b={0}".format(b_value))
    print("manual_W={0}".format(_W))
    print("manual_b={0}".format(_b))
    print("grad_W={0}".format(grad_W))
    print("grad_b={0}".format(grad_b))
    print("manual_grad_W={0}".format(manual_grad_W))
    print("manual_grad_b={0}".format(manual_grad_b))
    print("***********************")
    _W -= lr * manual_grad_W
    _b -= lr * manual_grad_b
```

I just try to apply gradient descent to a simple (w*X - b - Y)^2 model. I don't use Tensorflow's own optimizer purposefully, I want to understand the underlying graph update mechanisms. In order to check that the system calculates correct gradients, I implemented my own loss and gradient calculation functions for linear regression as well. Unfortunately, it seems that tensorflow does not calculate the loss function and the gradients as expected. Here is what I get as an output:

```
 ***********************
 loss=23.65999984741211
 manual_loss_value=23.659999999999997
 W=[ 0.30000001]
 b=[-0.30000001]
 manual_W=0.3
 manual_b=-0.3
 grad_W=[ 52.]
 grad_b=[ 15.59999943]
 manual_grad_W=52.0
 manual_grad_b=15.599999999999998
 ***********************
 ***********************
 loss=23.65999984741211
 manual_loss_value=20.81095744
 W=[ 0.24800001]
 b=[-0.31560001]
 manual_W=0.248
 manual_b=-0.3156
 grad_W=[ 52.]
 grad_b=[ 15.59999943]
 manual_grad_W=48.568
 manual_grad_b=14.4352
 ***********************
```

As you can see, tensorflow calculates incorrect loss value and gradients for W and b in the second iteration, actually the same ones as the first iteration. In some trials, it starts to diverge from the actual values from third or fourth iterations; not always in the second one. Am I doing something wrong here? As soon as I get the values of W and b and their gradients, I update their values with `tf.assign()` in the training loop. Does the problem lie here; is it a wrong way to update variables with tensorflow? It is really discouraging to run into such problems just at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the use of `tf.assign`. The command `tf.assign` creates assign nodes, that should be run to be effective. You should change to something like

```
assign_W_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
assign_b_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
assign_W_node = tf.assign(W, assign_W_placeholder)
assign_b_node = tf.assign(b, assign_b_placeholder)
```

and then in the for loop, add something like

```
sess.run(assign_W_node, feed_dict={assign_W_placeholder: new_W_value}
sess.run(assign_b_node, feed_dict={assign_b_placeholder: new_b_value}
```

After these, tensorflow and manual give the same results.

The complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def manual_loss(_w, _b, _x, _y):
    _loss = 0.0
    n = len(_x)
    for j in range(n):
       _loss += (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j]) ** 2
    return _loss


def manual_grads(_w, _b, _x, _y):
     n = len(_x)
     g_w = 0.0
     g_b = 0
     for j in range(n):
         g_w += 2.0 * (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j]) * _x[j]
         g_b += 2.0 * (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j])
     return g_w, g_b


# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([0.3], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-0.3], dtype=tf.float32)
_W = 0.3
_b = -0.3
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

assign_W_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
assign_b_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
assign_W_node = tf.assign(W, assign_W_placeholder)
assign_b_node = tf.assign(b, assign_b_placeholder)

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y))  # sum of the squares
grads = tf.gradients(loss, [W, b])
# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)  
lr = 0.001
for i in range(1000):
    results = sess.run([loss, W, b, grads], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    loss_value = results[0]
    W_value = results[1]
    b_value = results[2]
    grad_W = results[3][0]
    grad_b = results[3][1]
    manual_loss_value = manual_loss(_w=_W, _b=_b, _x=x_train, _y=y_train)
    manual_grad_W, manual_grad_b = manual_grads(_w=_W, _b=_b, _x=x_train, _y=y_train)
    new_W_value = W_value - lr * grad_W
    new_b_value = b_value - lr * grad_b
    sess.run([assign_W_node, assign_b_node], 
             feed_dict={assign_W_placeholder: new_W_value, assign_b_placeholder: new_b_value})
    print("***********************")
    print("loss={0}".format(loss_value))
    print("manual_loss_value={0}".format(manual_loss_value))
    print("W={0}".format(W_value))
    print("b={0}".format(b_value))
    print("manual_W={0}".format(_W))
    print("manual_b={0}".format(_b))
    print("grad_W={0}".format(grad_W))
    print("grad_b={0}".format(grad_b))
    print("manual_grad_W={0}".format(manual_grad_W))
    print("manual_grad_b={0}".format(manual_grad_b))
    print("***********************")
    _W -= lr * manual_grad_W
    _b -= lr * manual_grad_b
```

Comment: Then how it is possible with Tensorflow to use my own variable update mechanism and optimizers? I have to always use tf.placeholder I suppose?

Comment: The correct way to use `tf.assign` to manually update the variables is as follows: in the part where you define the graph (for instance after the line `grads = tf.gradients(...)`, add the lines `assign_W_....`, while in the for loop replace the lines `W = tf.assign(W, ...)` with `sess.run(assign_W_node,...)`

Comment: Everytime I call tf.assign(), it adds a new operation to the graph right?

Comment: yes, so at each iteration of the for loop you were adding a new assign operation. To me it is not very clear the behavior, since from the second iteration the first argument of the `tf.assign` is again an assign operation...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem of numeric precision. Numpy uses double floats by default (64 bits). You are declaring your tensors as `tf.float32`. Try to change them to `tf.float64`.

**Edit:** I think the difference is due to the exponentiation in the loss function. Try to change for a multiplication as in:

```
_loss += (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j]) * (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j])
```

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def manual_loss(_w, _b, _x, _y):
    _loss = 0.0
    n = len(_x)
    for j in range(n):
       diff = (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j])
       _loss += diff * diff

    return _loss


def manual_grads(_w, _b, _x, _y):
     n = len(_x)
     g_w = 0.0
     g_b = 0
     for j in range(n):
         g_w += 2.0 * (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j]) * _x[j]
         g_b += 2.0 * (_w * _x[j] + _b - _y[j])
     return g_w, g_b


# Model parameters
W = tf.Variable([0.3], dtype=tf.float64)
b = tf.Variable([-0.3], dtype=tf.float64)
_W = 0.3
_b = -0.3
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64)
linear_model = W * x + b
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64)

# loss
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y))  # sum of the squares
grads = tf.gradients(loss, [W, b])
# training data
x_train = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y_train = [0, -1, -2, -3]
# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)  
lr = 0.001
for i in range(10):
    with tf.device('cpu:0'):
        results = sess.run([loss, grads], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    loss_value = results[0]
    grad_W = results[1][0]
    grad_b = results[1][1]
    manual_loss_value = manual_loss(_w=_W, _b=_b, _x=x_train, _y=y_train)
    manual_grad_W, manual_grad_b = manual_grads(_w=_W, _b=_b, _x=x_train, _y=y_train)
    new_W_value = (W - lr * grad_W).eval(session = sess)
    new_b_value = (b - lr * grad_b).eval(session = sess)
    tf.assign(W, value=new_W_value).eval(session = sess)
    tf.assign(b, value=new_b_value).eval(session = sess)

    print("***********************")
    print("loss={0}".format(loss_value))
    print("manual_loss_value={0}".format(manual_loss_value))
    print("W={0}".format(W.eval(session = sess)))
    print("b={0}".format(b.eval(session = sess)))
    print("manual_W={0}".format(_W))
    print("manual_b={0}".format(_b))
    print("grad_W={0}".format(grad_W))
    print("grad_b={0}".format(grad_b))
    print("manual_grad_W={0}".format(manual_grad_W))
    print("manual_grad_b={0}".format(manual_grad_b))
    print("***********************")
    _W -= lr * manual_grad_W
    _b -= lr * manual_grad_b
```

Comment: I don't think that's the main issue, with the changes in my answer at iteration 1000 I have differences after the 5th decimal...

Comment: I have updated my answer. The result depends in the optimizations that Tensorflow and numpy are doing and if they are executed in the CPU or the GPU. I don't think it is reasonable to expect exactly the same results.

Comment: Actually @PietroTortella is right. There was an issue also with tf.assign too. I have included in my answer a version with his change and the precision changes.